# Is there any name or symbol for rational numbers with a bounded amount of decimals?

Tags: number-theory

As the title says, is there any name or symbol for rational numbers with a bounded amount of decimals?

For example, for the set of rational numbers that are multiples of $0.01$ (with two digits after the point; or equivalently, the subset of rational numbers that can be written using 100 as denominator), is there any specific mathematical symbol or concise way to name that?

Comment: $\{\frac{n}{100}~:~n\in\Bbb Z\} = \frac{1}{100}\Bbb Z$?

Comment: For your first question, yes, we refer to them as **terminating decimals.**  For more info, please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal

Comment: "Or less" is unnecessary. "Numbers with two decimal digits" include $2.30$ and $12.00,$ just as $230$ and $1200$ are integers and not just multiples of ten or of hundred. Don't forget "multiples of $0.01$".

Comment: @DavidK Under "number of decimal digits" , I would understand something else , namely the number of digits (including $0$) of a positive integer, so $1200$ has $4$. For this question, we have to specify that we mean the digits after the comman and to be able to uniquely count them, we should avoid unnecessary $0$-digts as in "$2.30$"

Comment: @Peter As the question has been reworded, "two digits after the decimal point" is fine in my opinion. And decimal numeric representations are not unique. Moreover, when the number of digits matters, so do trailing zeros. To a chemist, $2.3$ means something different from $2.30.$

Comment: @DavidK The edit improved the question. Unnecessary zeros only make sense in numerical mathematics or if we mention the result of a measurement and want to indicate how accurate it has been done. But for a definition of the terminating numbers, they have no merit.

Comment: @Peter We don't actually know what application OP had in mind. The title is described by terminating decimals but the last paragraph contradicts that answer. We could argue this back and forth forever but only OP could settle the argument.

Comment: Peregring-lk: Without more context to clarify why you want to define such sets of numbers and how you want to use them, the answer you have now may be the best you will get. If you want something else, perhaps you might try editing the question to explain what you want (or at least what you are currently seeing in the answer or comments that you *don't* want).

Comment: @DavidK The set $X$ I'm looking for is a set of valid quantities for "prices", which never take into account more than 2 digits after the decimal point, to say thinks like "be $p\in X$" to clearly specify that the least significant digit $\neq 0$ will be the second after the point at most, and also to promise that "$100\cdot p$" will always be an integer number.

Answer (score 4):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think in your question you meant to use the phrase, *finite number of digits* rather than *bounded amount of decimals*.

As amWhy pointed out in the comments, a **terminating decimal** is usually defined as a decimal number that contains a finite number of digits after the decimal point.

As for your final paragraph, I would refer to that set as "The set of all numbers with exactly two digits after the decimal point".

Or, if you don't mind $5.670$ being in your set, seeing as it has the same value as $5.67$, then as JMoravitz pointed out, you could instead write this set more concisely as $\frac{1}{100} \mathbb{Z} = 0.01\mathbb{Z}.$ However, if you consider $5.670$ and $5.67$ to be different numbers because you care about *accuracy* for example in chemistry, or you really only want to allow numbers with exactly two numbers after the decimal point in your set for whatever reason you may have, then this definition will not do, because $5.670 \in \frac{1}{100} \mathbb{Z},$ but $5.670 \notin$ { all numbers with exactly two digits after the decimal point }.

Comment: I would just add "multiples of $0.01$" as another possibility, even though it is exactly what is written in the question; sometimes the answer can be to do exactly what you were already doing.

Comment: I think the least unambiguosly way to specify the set I'm looking for is the set $X$ such as if $p\in X$, then $100\cdot p$ is an integer number (although that's polemic because, does $5.00\in\Bbb Z$?), or maybe that $100\cdot p$ is divisible by one.